# C# "/dev/ttyGS0" throws error "Invalid Argument"

Tags: serial, c#, mono

I'm working on an application for my pi in C# code. The overall idea is to create a usb "pc status" monitor that I can put inside my PC case.

My code that runs on the pi uses a ini file for settings. If I run:

```
sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0
```

then I change the port in the config to:

```
sPortName=/dev/ttyAMA0
```

then it works flawless. I am able to connect to the display and transmit the PC status messages exactly as I need to.

This is where my issue comes in. I need to use ttyGS0. If I tell it to use ttyGS0 it says "invalid argument". If I run

```
sudo systemctl start getty@ttyGS0
sudo systemctl stop getty@ttyGS0
```

Then try to launch the program, it says "Permission denied". If I try

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/ttyGS0
```

Then it says "Invalid argument" again. Any ideas why I cannot read from this port no matter how hard I try? Please keep in mind, this program is fully functional on ttyAMA0 but not on ttyGS0. Also, if I do

```
ls -la /dev/tty*
```

then it shows /dev/tty, /dev/tty0 to /dev/tty63, /dev/ttyAMA0, /dev/ttyGS0, /dev/ttyprintk

Also, I can use

```
echo "hello world" > /dev/ttyGS0
```

and it will send "hello world" to my application. Could it be a limitation of using C# somehow?

EDIT:
I believe it might be something to do with using C#. I don't know how or why it is happening with one serial port and not another, but I wrote a quick python script

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyGS0')
ser.write(b'hello world')
ser.close()
```

And it is working perfectly. So I haven't got a clue, lol.

Comment: It's usually called /dev/ttyS0 (no gee).

Comment: It shows up as ttyGS0 and the pi g_serial documentation calls it ttyGS0. Also, running getty on it works and allows me to connect with serial console, so I don't think that is it.

Comment: What does ```ls -la /dev/tty*``` show? Edit your question and add that.

Comment: @Dougie Added the info you wanted me to.